# PHP 5.4 and UTF-8 not working

Tags: php, mysqli, utf-8

Enviroment: Windows NT WSP-IIS24 6.1 build 7601 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Server Edition Service Pack 1) i586 running IIS with PHP 5.4 and MySQL 5.0.10.
All text tables is set to UTF-8.
mbstring is added to PHP and configured in php.

When I open the connectiton the the database I see to it that UTF-8 is the default.

I set UTF-8 in the header. Still all non US chars is made into ?.

What am I missing?

I should add that the text I retriving from the database is mandarin, russian, spansish among other languages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: I have seen that thread but it dint help, strangely.

Comment: You will have to provide the info required to reproduce the issue. Also, you have multiple components involved here, which of them is at fault?

Comment: You will have to add a lot more detail with actual code samples to illustrate what you're doing. There is *some* problem *somewhere* in the details, but since you're not showing any details we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `SET NAMES 'UTF8'` after connecting to MySQL:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pw", "db");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Failed to connect to mySQL: ' .mysqli_connect_errno());
}

/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!$con->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $con->error);
}
```

As the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) says:

> SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL
>   statements to the server... It also specifies the character set that the server should
>   use for sending results back to the client.